# Issue with allocating memory for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I was asking similar question earlier. The answers I got pinpointed my mistake to not having set aside a memory for the pointer. The following piece of code still complains error: cannot convert ‘void*’ to ‘double’ in assignment. Does it mean that all elements in array are set aside as NULL?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int N = 2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
double *p[N];

for(int i = 0; i<N; ++i){
    *p[i]=malloc(sizeof(double));   
}   

    *p[0] = 1.0;
    *p[1] = 2.0;
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] <<endl; 
    *p[0] = 5.0;
    *p[1] = 6.0;
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] <<endl;     
    return 0;
```

}

I need an array to solve a problem that I have. The array needs to be in global memory (in CUDA), which needs to be a pointer that GPUs can read/write from/to.

Comment: This is C++ so don't use malloc. Use `new` and event better would be `std::vector`.

Comment: I would recommend that you start with some basic tutorial and/or books. The question demonstrates that you are missing basic knowledge of some of the core building blocks to the language.

Comment: @RedX: This might be C++, but it's still valid to use `malloc()`, either to take advantage of `realloc()` or for interoperability reasons. Also, you do not want to use many abstractions when defining your own special containers for example.

Answer (score 2):

p[i]=malloc(sizeof(double));

..get rid of the '*' that is dereferencing a double type and trying to assign malloc() result to it.

Comment: I still get the same error when I get rid of that *. Could there any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
*p[i]=malloc(sizeof(double));
```

One dereference too many, and you are running afool of C++'s stricter type checking. Use:

```
p[i]=(double*)malloc(sizeof**p);
```

Or even better C++-style:

```
p[i] = new double*;
```

Not freeing the allocated memory is acceptable only because you immediately exit the program. Better not get in the habit though. Always use the complementary deallocator, e.g.: `free()` for `malloc()`, `delete` for `new` and `delete []` for `new []`.

Anyway, why use pointers there at all? Also, idiomatic C++ puts nearly all raw arrays into `std::vector` and other containers.

Comment: In the problem that I have, I need to communicate between CPU and GPUs multiple times. GPUs need access to data in CPU, and passing pointers instead of whole data seemed like a good idea.

Comment: @MisterSpock: Anyway, that's no reason not to use one array containing the values directly. It's not even reason to eschew standard containers. You can get the address of anything you want in C, just for the asking.

Comment: @Dedupplicator I'll look into that. That's for the suggestion.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The last example is wrong, `p` is an array of pointers to double, if you are going to assign to the i-th element you need to pass a pointer to `double`, not a pointer to pointer to `double` (drop the `*` in `double*`)

Comment: @MisterSpock: I have never done GPU programming, but passing a pointer will only make sense if the GPU can access the actual memory that the CPU is using. I would check the documentation as of whether that is the case (I have a hunch that it is not, and that you need to move the data back and forth)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna do this:

```
double* p = new double[2];

p[0] = 1.0;
p[1] = 2.0;
p[0] = 5.0;
p[1] = 6.0;
```

Avoid malloc and generally be careful about allocating memory on the heap (as already indicated, you might read more about the C++ memory management).

Cheers!